# Premiere proxies no audio, codec issue?

Tags: premiere, adobe-media-encoder

I'm away from my main desktop, and working on my underpowered laptop. I'm creating proxies for some .MTS files that a client gave me (I don't know which camera was used). Unfortunately after Media Encoder generated my proxy files there is no audio. I checked the original source video file in encoder and it says it has no audio, even though there is audio, and it is recognized in premiere. Note: when I first important the original video files into Premiere it said it had to install a Dolby codec and did so.

Any idea how I can get audio from the original files recognized in Media Encoder so I can generate proxies with audio?

Here is a sample video: http://www.filedropper.com/intro1jan

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the files to .m2ts seemed to have solved the issue.